# Extracting data from tbody with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some data from this HTML using BeautifulSoup. I only want to return `data-buyout="1 alchemy" data-ign="DanForeverr" data-league="Standard" data-name="Sulphur Wastes Map" data-seller="NoCocent" data-sellerid="None" data-tab="~price 1 alch" data-x="6" data-y="7"`*`, but I am not getting any results. I am using the code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
parsed = soup.find_all('tbody', class=re.compile('^data-'))
```

```html
<tbody class="item item-live-c324ceb98e25716a0fad0727e0cd64e3" data-buyout="1 alchemy" data-ign="DanForeverr" data-league="Standard" data-name="Sulphur Wastes Map" data-seller="NoCocent" data-sellerid="None" data-tab="~price 1 alch" data-x="6" data-y="7" id="item-container-0">
 <tr class="first-line">
  <td class="icon-td">
   <div class="icon">
    <img alt="Item icon" src="https://web.poecdn.com/image/Art/2DItems/Maps/AtlasMaps/SulphurWastes3.png?scale=1&amp;w=1&amp;h=1&amp;v=48802019c4a2e88af038d75ec1e4b31e3"/>
    \n
    <div class="sockets" style="position: absolute;">
     \n
     <div class="sockets-inner" style="position: relative; width:94px;">
      \n
     </div>
     \n
    </div>
   </div>
  </td>
  <td class="item-cell">
   <h5>
    <a class="title itemframe0" href="#" onclick="return false;" target="_blank">
     Sulphur Wastes Map
    </a>
    <span class="found-time-ago">
     2 months ago
    </span>
   </h5>
   <ul class="requirements proplist">
    <li>
     <span class="sortable" data-name="ilvl">
      ilvl: 80
     </span>
    </li>
   </ul>
   <span class="sockets-raw" style="display:none">
   </span>
   <ul class="item-mods">
   </ul>
  </td>
  <td class="table-stats">
   <table>
    <tr class="calibrate">
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
     <th>
     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cell-first">
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Quality
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Phys.
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Elem.
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      APS
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      DPS
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      pDPS
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      eDPS
     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cell-first">
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="q" data-value="0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="pd" data-value="0.0">
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-ed="" data-name="ed" data-value="0.0">
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="aps" data-value="0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="dps" data-value="0.0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="pdps" data-value="0.0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="edps" data-value="0.0">
      \xa0
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cell-second">
     <th class="cell-empty">
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Armour
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Evasion
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Shield
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Block
     </th>
     <th class="disabled" colspan="2">
      Crit.
     </th>
     <th colspan="2">
      Tier
     </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cell-second">
     <td class="cell-empty">
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="armour" data-value="0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="evasion" data-value="0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="shield" data-value="0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="block" data-value="0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="crit" data-value="0">
      \xa0
     </td>
     <td class="sortable property " colspan="2" data-name="level" data-value="13">
      13
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to find tag attributes in the tag class, that will not work.

Why not find it by ID? Just assure that it contains the substring before the 0.

```
soup.select("tbody[id*=item-container-]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can't really do that, you can extract specific information from that tag like.

Define x = html that you posted something like : `x = '''<tbody class="item item-live-c324ceb98e25716a0fad0727e0cd64e3" data-buyout="1 alchemy" data-ign="DanForeverr" data-league="Standard" data-name="Sulphur Wastes Map" data-seller="NoCocent" data-sellerid="None" data-tab="~price 1 alch" data-x="6" data-y="7" id="item-container-0">'''`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(x,'lxml')

this_class = soup.findAll('tbody',{'class':'item item-live-c324ceb98e25716a0fad0727e0cd64e3'})
#This is used to pinpoint the exact tbody (you can do it your way),
# but it's useful because you give it the exacty key-value. (Mostly can't miss)

for i in this_class:
    print(i['data-buyout'])
    print(i['data-ign'])
    print(i['data-name'])
    print(i['id'])
```

You can print each value of these attributes, but if you **use** `soup.findAll` or `sou.find` it's **NOT** only going to print the (*one*)**branch** but also the whole **tree** *(children)*

Answer (score 0):

a combonation of the following solved my issue

```
parsed = soup.select("tbody[id*=item-container-]")
for i in parsed:
    print(i['data-buyout'])
    print(i['data-ign'])
    print(i['data-name'])
    print(i['id'])
```